What are the hidden assumptions in "Nonlinear Estimation With Radar Observations"?
The paper "Nonlinear Estimation With Radar Observations" (Kenneth S. Miller, Donald M. Leskiw; 1982 IEEE) reports on an improved method for radar tracking with an Extended Kalman Filter (EKF). The authors make a number of assumptions which let them simplify the formula for the update step in their EKF.
It seems to me that some of the assumptions are not mentioned. Specifically, they go from equation (8):
$$
\left[\begin{matrix}
  x_e \\
  y_e
\end{matrix}\right] = \left[\begin{matrix}
  x_0 \\
  y_0
\end{matrix}\right] + P_e \left[\begin{matrix}
  \cos~\theta_0 \\
  \sin~\theta_0
\end{matrix}\right] [(r-r_0)/\sigma_r^2] + P_e \left[\begin{matrix}
  -\sin~\theta_0 \\
  \cos~\theta_0
\end{matrix}\right] [(r-r_0)/r_0\sigma_r^2]
$$
to the approximation in equation (10):
$$
\left[\begin{matrix}
  x_e \\
  y_e
\end{matrix}\right] \approx \left[\begin{matrix}
  x_0 \\
  y_0
\end{matrix}\right] + \left[\begin{matrix}
  \cos~\theta_0 \\
  \sin~\theta_0
\end{matrix}\right] (r-r_0) + \left[\begin{matrix}
  -\sin~\theta_0 \\
  \cos~\theta_0
\end{matrix}\right] r_0(r-r_0)
$$
The stated assumption is that the initial position estimation covariance $P_0$ is negligible compared to the measurement covariance $R$, which lets them simplify $P_e$ from:
$$
P_e^{-1} = P_0^{-1} + H_0'R^{-1}H_0
$$
to:
$$
P_e \approx H_0^{-1}RH_0'^{-1}
$$
However, it seems to me that they also need to assume that the variance of the range measurement $\sigma_r^2$ is similar to the linearized variance of the angle measurement $\sigma_\theta^2$:
$$
\sigma_r^2 \approx \sigma_\theta^2r_0^2
$$
It seems to be the case if one multiplies the approximated $P_e$ by either of the column matrices. For example:
$$
P_e \begin{bmatrix}
  \cos~\theta_0 \\
  \sin~\theta_0
\end{bmatrix} /\sigma_r^2 =
\left[\begin{matrix}\frac{\sigma_{\theta}^{2} r_{0}^{2} \sin^{2}{\left(\theta_{0} \right)}}{\sigma_{r}^{2}} + \cos^{2}{\left(\theta_{0} \right)} & \frac{\left(- \sigma_{\theta}^{2} r_{0}^{2} + \sigma_{r}^{2}\right) \sin{\left(2 \theta_{0} \right)}}{2 \sigma_{r}^{2}}\\\frac{\left(- \sigma_{\theta}^{2} r_{0}^{2} + \sigma_{r}^{2}\right) \sin{\left(2 \theta_{0} \right)}}{2 \sigma_{r}^{2}} & \frac{\sigma_{\theta}^{2} r_{0}^{2} \cos^{2}{\left(\theta_{0} \right)}}{\sigma_{r}^{2}} + \sin^{2}{\left(\theta_{0} \right)}\end{matrix}\right]
$$
Now, if $\sigma_r^2 \approx \sigma_\theta^2r_0^2$, that matrix simplifies to:
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
  \sin^2\theta_0 + \cos^2\theta_0 & (1-1)\sin(2\theta_0) \\
  (1-1)\sin(2\theta_0) & \cos^2\theta_0 + \sin^2\theta_0
\end{bmatrix} \approx \begin{bmatrix}
  1 & 0 \\
  0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
$$
Am I getting this right?

I think you have the basic idea down, and maybe what you meant is to say this, but I'll write it out anyways.
We are given
\begin{equation}
H_{0} = \begin{bmatrix} \cos(\theta_{0}) & \sin(\theta_{0}) \\ \frac{-\sin(\theta_{0})}{r_{0}} & \frac{\cos(\theta_{0})}{r_{0}} \end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
R = \begin{bmatrix} \sigma_{r}^{2} & 0 \\ 0 & \sigma_{\theta}^{2} \end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
P_{e}^{-1} = P_{0}^{-1} + H_{0}^{T}R^{-1}H_{0}
\end{equation}
Since $R$ is a diagonal matrix, we can find $R^{-1}$ as
\begin{equation}
R^{-1} = \begin{bmatrix} \frac{1}{\sigma_{r}^{2}} & 0 \\ 0 & \frac{1}{\sigma_{\theta}^{2}} \end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}
We then note that
\begin{equation}
P_{e} = \left(H_{0}^{T}R^{-1}H_{0}\right)^{-1}
\end{equation}
Calculating $P_{e}^{-1}$ yields
\begin{align}
P_{e}^{-1} &= \begin{bmatrix} \cos(\theta_{0}) & \frac{-\sin(\theta_{0})}{r_{0}} \\ \sin(\theta_{0}) & \frac{\cos(\theta_{0})}{r_{0}} \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} \frac{1}{\sigma_{r}^{2}} & 0 \\ 0 & \frac{1}{\sigma_{\theta}^{2}} \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} \cos(\theta_{0}) & \sin(\theta_{0}) \\ \frac{-\sin(\theta_{0})}{r_{0}} & \frac{\cos(\theta_{0})}{r_{0}} \end{bmatrix} \\ &= \begin{bmatrix} \frac{\cos(\theta_{0})}{\sigma_{r}^{2}} & \frac{-\sin(\theta_{0})}{r_{0}\sigma_{theta}^{2}}  \\ \frac{\sin(\theta_{0})}{\sigma_{r}^{2}} & \frac{\cos(\theta_{0})}{r_{0}\sigma_{\theta}^{2}}\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} \cos(\theta_{0}) & \sin(\theta_{0}) \\ \frac{-\sin(\theta_{0})}{r_{0}} & \frac{\cos(\theta_{0})}{r_{0}} \end{bmatrix} \\ &= \begin{bmatrix} \frac{\cos^{2}(\theta_{0})}{\sigma_{r}^{2}} + \frac{\sin^{2}(\theta_{0})}{r_{0}^{2}\sigma_{\theta}^{2}} & \frac{\cos(\theta_{0})\sin(\theta_{0})}{\sigma_{r}^{2}} - \frac{\cos(\theta_{0})\sin(\theta_{0})}{r_{0}^{2}\sigma_{\theta}^{2}} \\ \frac{\cos(\theta_{0})\sin(\theta_{0})}{\sigma_{r}^{2}} - \frac{\cos(\theta_{0})\sin(\theta_{0})}{r_{0}^{2}\sigma_{\theta}^{2}} & \frac{\sin^{2}(\theta_{0})}{\sigma_{r}^{2}} + \frac{\cos^{2}(\theta_{0})}{r_{0}^{2}\sigma_{\theta}^{2}} \end{bmatrix}
\end{align}
Then, plugging in for the linearized variance of the angle measurement and calculating $P_{e}$ from this, we get
\begin{align}
P_{e} &= (P_{e}^{-1})^{-1} \\ &= \begin{bmatrix} \frac{\cos^{2}(\theta_{0})}{\sigma_{r}^{2}} + \frac{\sin^{2}(\theta_{0})}{r_{0}^{2}\sigma_{\theta}^{2}} & \frac{\cos(\theta_{0})\sin(\theta_{0})}{\sigma_{r}^{2}} - \frac{\cos(\theta_{0})\sin(\theta_{0})}{r_{0}^{2}\sigma_{\theta}^{2}} \\ \frac{\cos(\theta_{0})\sin(\theta_{0})}{\sigma_{r}^{2}} - \frac{\cos(\theta_{0})\sin(\theta_{0})}{r_{0}^{2}\sigma_{\theta}^{2}} & \frac{\sin^{2}(\theta_{0})}{\sigma_{r}^{2}} + \frac{\cos^{2}(\theta_{0})}{r_{0}^{2}\sigma_{\theta}^{2}} \end{bmatrix}^{-1} \\ &= \left(\frac{1}{\sigma_{r}^{2}}\begin{bmatrix} \cos^{2}(\theta_{0})+\sin^{2}(\theta_{0}) & \cos(\theta_{0})\sin(\theta_{0}) - \cos(\theta_{0})\sin(\theta_{0}) \\ \cos(\theta_{0})\sin(\theta_{0}) - \cos(\theta_{0})\sin(\theta_{0}) & \cos^{2}(\theta_{0})+\sin^{2}(\theta_{0})\end{bmatrix}\right)^{-1} \\ &= \left(\frac{1}{\sigma_{r}^{2}}\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}\right)^{-1} \\ & = \sigma_{r}^{2}\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix} \\ &= r_{0}^{2}\sigma_{\theta}^{2}\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}
\end{align}
So, you are correct, but the key is the scale factor on the identity, and switching between the two equal representations depending on which column vector you multiply $P_{e}$ with to get to equation $(10)$.
So, in summary, it seems they make the assumptions of $P_{0}^{-1}$ negligible and a linearized angle measurement variance, which seem to be reasonable assumptions for an EKF IMO.

Thank you, your approach is indeed much more clear.
